# Almost sure transversality of smooth random maps

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, pr.probability, stochastic-processes

I still am  novice as far as probability is concerned and after fruitlessly Googling for an answer for a few days  I thought I might have a better chance  with MO.

Let me   first formulate the question/claim. $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$ $\DeclareMathOperator{\ev}{\mathbf{ev}}$ $\newcommand{\bu}{\boldsymbol{u}}$ $\newcommand{\bsU}{\boldsymbol{U}}$

Fix positive integers $N\geq n$ and suppose that $\bu$ is  a Gaussian random map $\bR^N\to\bR^n$  satisfying the following conditions.

**Regularity.** The random map is a.s. $C^\infty$.

**$0$-jet ampleness.** For any $x\in \bR^N$ the $\bR^n$-valued Gaussian random variable $\bu(x)$   has a nondegenerate covariance form.    Equivalently this means that its probability distribution $\Gamma_x$ is  absolutely continuous  with respect  to the Lebesgue measure on $\bR^n$. Another, more geometric, way  of phrasing this is that $\Gamma_x(V)=0$ for any proper vector subspace of $\bR^n$.

*I claim that under  the above   assumptions one can conclude that $0\in\bR^n$ is almost surely a regular value of $\bu$.*

Here is some evidence backing this claim.

**I.** The conclusion is true in the case  $N=n$.  One source for this result is Proposition 6.5 in  the book

> **Level sets and extrema of random processes and fields** by Azais and Wschebor, Wiley, 2009.

The earliest reference on this type of question seems to be a paper by Bulinskaya in the 60s.  Let me mention  that in Proposition 6.12 in the above  book the  a.s.  transversality  is proven   for any $N\geq n$  when the $0$-jet  ampleness condition  is  replaced by a stronger requirement I would call $1$-jet ampleness.  This condition imposes additional  restrictions on the differential of $\bu$. I would rather not involve the  derivatives of $\bu$.

**II.** The conclusion is true  for a large  class of random maps constructed as follows.

Fix a finite  dimensional   subspace  $\bsU\subset C^\infty(\bR^N,\bR^n)$. We assume that $\bsU$ is ample, i.e.,  for any $x\in \bR^N$ the evaluation map

$$\ev_x:\bsU\to\bR^n,\;\;\bsU\ni \bu \mapsto \bu(x)\in\bR^n $$

is onto.  Next fix an inner product  $(-,-)$  on $\bsU$ and denote by $\Gamma$ the Gaussian measure on $\bsU$ determined by this inner product. An element $\bu\in\bsU$ is thus a smooth random map $\bR^N\to\bR^n$.  The ampleness of $\bsU$ implies the $0$-jet amplenes condition on $\bu$.

One can verify rather easily that $0$ is .s. a regular value of this random  map $\bu$.  The argument goes as follows.     Consider the incidence set $\newcommand{\eR}{\mathscr{R}}$

$$\eR=\bigl\lbrace\; (x,\bu)\in \bR^N\times \bsU;\;\;\bu(x)=0\;\bigr\rbrace. $$

The ampleness  of $\bsU$ implies  that $\eR$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $(N-n)+\dim\bsU\geq \dim\bsU$.  We next observe that if $\bu$ is a regular value of the  natural  map

$$\pi:\eR\to\bsU,\;\;\eR\ni(x,\bu)\mapsto \bu\in \bsU $$

then $0$ is a regular value of $\bu$.  Sard's theorem applied to the smooth map $\pi$ implies that $0$ is a.s.  a regular value  of $\bu$.

It is very likely this question   has been investigated by people working on    random maps.   As I said in the beginning I was not able to find  references  on this question. Any  additional info you might have is greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance!